# gnuplot plotting the difference interval of two dates

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following datafile for which I need to plot the difference interval:

---

```
CREATEDDATE         LASTUPDATEDATE      HRS MINS SEC    DIFF_INTERVAL
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:24:39  0   3   15      +00 00:03:15.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:22:18  0   0   54      +00 00:00:54.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:22:03  0   0   39      +00 00:00:39.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:24:39  0   3   15      +00 00:03:15.000000
```

---

I couldn't plot (didn't know how) the data as above so I tried to format the datafile to have only 2 columns: creationdate (timefmt "%d-%b/%H:%M:%S") and convert DIFF interval into seconds, but still my graph looks very bad.

---

```
createiondate           diff interval in sec
10-JUN/10:10:24         48
10-JUN/10:10:24         195
10-JUN/10:10:24         195
```

---

Here is how my approach looks:

---

```
set title "Test"
set terminal png truecolor
xequiv = 100
yezuiv = 250
set output "/home/user/script/photo.png"
set autoscale
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%b/%H:%M:%S"
set xtics format "%M %S"
set xlabel "Creationdate"
set ylabel "Diff interval in seconds"
set ytics 50 nomirror
set style data lines
set grid
set key outside
set terminal png size 1400,650
plot "/home/user/script/spool.file" using 1:2 title "Orders" lc rgb "red" lw 2
```

---

Do you have suggestions on how to approach it or is it even possible to plot the diff interval of two dates?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want plot time difference (in seconds) versus the creation date. With your data I see equivalent 3 possibilities:

1. calculate the difference between LASTUPDATEDATE and CREATEDATE
2. take columns 5,6, and 7 to calculate your seconds
3. convert column 9 into seconds

To me, the second way looks like the easiest.
However, in your example data CREATEDATE is identical (it's not fully clear to me how you want to display it. Well, on top of each other). So, for nicer illustration I took the LASTUPDATEDATE in the example below.

**Code:**

```
### plot time interval vs. date time
reset session

$Data <<EOD
CREATEDDATE         LASTUPDATEDATE      HRS MINS SEC    DIFF_INTERVAL
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:24:39  0   3   15      +00 00:03:15.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:22:18  0   0   54      +00 00:00:54.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:22:03  0   0   39      +00 00:00:39.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:24:39  0   3   15      +00 00:03:15.000000
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S"

set format x "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S" time 
set xtics rotate by 45 right
set key top left
set ylabel "Time difference / s"

myDuration(c1,c2,c3) = column(c1)*3600 + column(c2)*60 + column(c3)

plot $Data u (timecolumn(3,myTimeFmt)):(myDuration(5,6,7)) w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc rgb "red" ti "Duration"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Indeed, the CREATEDATE is identical, therefore is quite challenging to display it. I tried to apply your solution and i get the following error: "unknown type in magnitude()".

Comment: hmm, haven't heard about this error. Does it say which line? Do you use the above code as copy&paste? If not, please show your code you're actually using.

Comment: line 0: unknown type in magnitude()
Code:
`set title "Test"
set output "/home/user/script/photo.png"
myTimeFmt="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S"
set xtics rotate by 45 #right
set key top left
set xlabel "Creationdate timeframe"
set ylabel "Time difference / s"
myDuration(c1,c2,c3)=column(c1)*3600+column(c2)*60+column(c3)
plot "/home/user/script//spool.file" using (timecolumn(3,myTimeFmt)):(myDuration(5,6,7)) w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc rgb "red" title "Duration"`

Comment: I've seen now that the error occures at the following line:
'plot "/home/user/script//spool.file" using (timecolumn(3,myTimeFmt)):(myDuration(5,6,7)) w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc rgb "red" title "Duration"'. It might be an issue caused by the gnuplot version i'm using (4.2)?
Thank you!

Comment: Ouch, such an old version? Have you updated now? Is it working now? If one of the answers solved your problem, then please mark it as acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me exactly how you want to lay out the plot, but here is an example using your original data sample and plotting every line as a separate entry along x (`using 0`).

```
$DATA << EOD
CREATEDDATE         LASTUPDATEDATE      HRS MINS SEC    DIFF_INTERVAL
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:24:39  0   3   15      +00 00:03:15.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:22:18  0   0   54      +00 00:00:54.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:22:03  0   0   39      +00 00:00:39.000000
10-JUN-20 10:21:24  10-JUN-20 10:24:39  0   3   15      +00 00:03:15.000000
EOD

time_format = "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S"

set xtics 1 format "line %0g"
set ytics time format "%tH:%tM:%tS"
set ylabel "Elapsed time"
set yrange [0:*]
unset key
set offset .5, .5, 30, 0

plot $DATA skip 1 using 0:(timecolumn(3,time_format) - timecolumn(1,time_format)) with points
```

[image]

If instead you want to use the first column time as the x coordinates (all the points in your sample set will be at the same x coordinate) replace `using 0` with `using (timecolumn(1,time_format))` and change the xtics format accordingly.